# UIInterfaceOrientation for default screen in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, screen-orientation, uiinterfaceorientation

I am developing one iphone app, and i want to support  all orientations.

The problem is that I want the  default.png  to be launched in the proper way according to the orientation at start up. Can someone post some method or proper name for default images so that I can rotate it?

Comment: it is difficult to understand what you are asking...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically there is a landscape "default" image only for iPad. in iPhone you should suplly only one in the  main orientation of your app.

anyway, if you want to do that, there is a workaround posted in this question:

[Auto-rotate the default application image according to current landscape mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/883927/auto-rotate-the-default-application-image-according-to-current-landscape-mode)